# 0 A.D(game) doesn't work after I updated to linux 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, games

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04(Bionic Beaver). Everything was fine until I ran 0 a.d that I had installed on Ubuntu 16.04. The application is version Alpha 23 Ken Wood. That is version 0.2.3. This is the message I recieve:

```
  dbus[7807]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What do I do? Experts?

---

Full code:

```
    milkybar@Milkybar-Computer:~$ 0ad
TIMER| InitVfs: 83.6046 ms
Writing the mainlog at /home/milkybar/.config/0ad/logs/mainlog.html
TIMER| CONFIG_Init: 39.5669 ms
Sound: AlcInit success, using OpenAL Soft
TIMER| shutdown ConfigDB: 1.816 us
TIMER| resource modules: 4.23742 ms
TIMER TOTALS (9 clients)
-----------------------------------------------------
  tc_pool_alloc: 0 c (0x)
  tc_png_decode: 0 c (0x)
  tc_dds_transform: 0 c (0x)
  tc_transform: 0 c (0x)
  tc_plain_transform: 0 c (0x)
  tc_ShaderGLSLLink: 0 c (0x)
  tc_ShaderGLSLCompile: 0 c (0x)
  tc_ShaderValidation: 0 c (0x)
  xml_validation: 0 c (0x)
-----------------------------------------------------
TIMER| shutdown misc: 314.571 us
TIMER| InitVfs: 244.405 ms
Writing the mainlog at /home/milkybar/.config/0ad/logs/mainlog.html
TIMER| CONFIG_Init: 3.3456 ms
Sound: AlcInit success, using OpenAL Soft
dbus[7807]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
milkybar@Milkybar-Computer:~$
```

Comment: Well, this same application worked perfectly before i updated Ubuntu. Is this not some kind of bug in Ubuntu rather than in the application?

Comment: Well, you might be right. There is a related [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl2/+bug/1775067), including some [workarounds](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl2/+bug/1775067/comments/7).

Comment: I am relatively new to Linux. So maybe for more people like me out there, is there an easier workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, there may be a bug in the game that causes this error.

To run the game, I first uninstalled the game that I installed from Ubuntu Software Center using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove 0ad 0ad-data
```

Then I reinstalled the game using:

```
sudo snap install 0ad
```

The same version of 0 a.d. from snap doesn't have this problem.